# Laravel Eloquent Relations: ->latest()

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

What is the function of latest() in laravel?

Example:

```
public function activity()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Activity')
        ->with(['user', 'subject'])
        ->latest();
}
```

From [Build an activity feed in Laravel](https://github.com/laracasts/Build-An-Activity-Feed-in-Laravel/blob/master/app/User.php) on line 44.

I've been looking in the laravel documentation, but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`latest()` is a function defined in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` Class. It's job is very simple. This is how it is defined.

```
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
{
    return $this->orderBy($column, 'desc');
}
```

So, It will just `orderBy` with the column you provide in `descending` order with the default column will be `created_at`.

Comment: Can we pass array to the latest() method?

Comment: @TahirAfridi, as mentioned in the documentation, "By default, the result will be ordered by the created_at column. Or, you may pass the column name that you wish to sort by"

Comment: In short: It will by default get the NEWEST database entry according to the created_at column.

Comment: not intuitive at all, I thought latest() would be the opposite of first().

Comment: You can use `oldest()` as the opposite to `latest()` also.

Comment: It's strange – I have a query that needs to fetch millions of records, but when I try to get the latest one using orderBy('created_at', 'desc'), it seems to break the application. However, when I use the latest method instead, the query runs without any issues.

Answer (score 8):

->latest() fetches the most recent set of data from the Database. In short, it sorts the data fetched, using the 'created_at' column to chronologically order the data.

Comment: Does it really fetch?

Comment: Yes, It fetches and returns an array of records by their most recent

Comment: It doesn't fetch anything, it returns a query builder with the ordering chained to it. You would still need to call something like ->get(), ->first() etc. on to fetch any rows from the database

Comment: No it does not fetch. It needs the output from the get()

Answer (score 7):

Add `->get()` on your code like this:

```
public function activity()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Activity')
        ->with(['user', 'subject'])
        ->latest()->get();
}
```

Comment: have you tested this code ? and have documentation of this.

Comment: @pankajkumar this is working. to get a collection use `get` if you want get single row use `first`

Answer (score 0):

`latest()` function in Laravel used to get latest records from database using default column `created_at`.

`latest()`is the equivalent to `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`