# How do i fetch the latest comment for with that specific model, and the user for that comment?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model that is "static". Its contains games with various information about them. And users can comment on games with a polymorphic relationship. The problem is that I want to fetch the 10 latest games that has been commented on, and that user for that comment. So `Game` doesn't have a relationship to `Users`.

I have manage to solve it like this:

```php
$games = Game::join('comments', 'games.id', '=', 'comments.commentable_id')
->where('comments.commentable_type', Game::class)
->latest('comments.created_at')
->groupBy('games.id')
->take(10)
->withCount('comments')
->get()->each(function($game){
    $game->comment = $game->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $game->user = User::find($game->comment->user_id);
    return $game;
});
```

But this creates a lot of queries, I would like to eager load, don't have that N+1 problem everyone is talking about.

I got another solution to add this function to `Game`

```php
class Game extends Model {
    public function latestComment() {
        return $this->morphOne(Comment::class, 'commentable')->latest();
    }
}
```

And run the query like `$games = Game::withCount('comments')->with(['latestComment.user'])->take(10)->get();`

But it seems as this query doesn't fetch the users. Only the first user is fetched. And also the `comments_count` (`withCount()`) only returns a value for the firsts result.

So I'm stuck!

**The expected result**
Load the 10 latest games with the latest comment for that game, with the totalt count of comments for that game, with the user for the latest comment - everything eager loaded to avoid the n+1 problem.

Is it possible?
ps. prepared a sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07570

**Edit**
It seems as the second query in this question "takes" (`take(10)`) takes the first 10 games in from games table, regardless if they have comments or not. If I have 15 comments for games with IDs from 20-30, the query will check IDs from 1 to 10.

If I run the second query in my question, with just the fiddle data in my comment table. Result 10 will contain game with id of 10, no user, no `comments_count` etc.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755804/laravel-eloquent-relations-latest ?

Comment: Yes, what about latest? =)

Comment: In your sample data, only the first game has comments.

Comment: I don't think so, but I have updated the fiddle and removed unnecessary data.

Comment: Your `games.id` values are `1...9`, your `comments.commentable_id` values are `1, 14, 139, 242`. So, only the first game actually has comments.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I updated the fiddle. Say that it is only one comment in `comments` table. The query seems to fetch 10 games either way.

Comment: If you want to ignore games without comments, you can add `->having('comments_count', '>', 0)` to the query (doesn't work with pagination).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir That solves the problem with fetching uncommented games, yes - but; the query still only take games in IDs order from the games table. It doesn't fetches the 10 games, with the latest comments.

Comment: You want to order the games by the latest comment's `created_at`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes precis

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified `withCount()` to get the latest `comments.created_at`:

```php
$games = Game::withCount(['comments',
        'comments as latest_comment' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)'));
    }])
    ->having('comments_count', '>', 0)
    ->orderByDesc('latest_comment')
    ->with('latestComment.user')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would access directly the comments table/model, query for the last 10 comments, `pluck` the games ids, and use them to query the games model/table with a `whereIn`.

Also add to the games query a `selectRaw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments where ...) as commentCount')`