# Get latest date from array of models with Eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of model entities, each one has a used_at carbon timestamp, I was wondering how can I retrieve the last model to be used (latest used_at) timestamp of the record of models.

```
$models = Model::all();
```

How can I get the last used model with Eloquent?

Comment: May be `$models = Model::latest('used_at')->get();` for model instance only the last record `$models = Model::latest('used_at')->first();` or ` `$models = Model::orderBy('used_at', 'DESC')->first();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Relations: ->latest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755804/laravel-eloquent-relations-latest)

Answer (score 0):

```php
Model::latest('used_at')->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest