# Eloquent relationship only returns result for first result in array

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, relationship

I have the following model with these relationsships:

```
class Site extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function tests() {
        return $this->hasMany(Test::class,'requestedUrl','frontpage');
    }

    public function latestTests() {
        return $this->tests()->latest()->take(1);
    }   
}
```

I have the following eloquent statement:

```
$sites = Site::
    ->with('latestTest')
    ->orderBy($sort, $direction)
    ->paginate($size);
```

But in the result it is only the first returned record that contains `latestTest`. I assume it's because of `take(1)` but if I remove that I will choke the server since it seems to be fetching all the tests (100k+ rows) before servering the latest (at least that is what I can see in my queries log).

So how do I get the latest test "the right way"?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755804/laravel-eloquent-relations-latest

Comment: I understand how latest work but since I dont want all results but only the most recent related record it doesn't work since it maxes out the server. I can't eager load in relationsship, ie. ->first(), so what to do without using ->latest()?

Comment: use return $this->tests()->latest()->fisrt();

Comment: Thats when I get an error on "addEagerConstraints()" so that doesn't work either..

Comment: So You need the latest test of Each site right ??

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai, yes that is correct