# how to get latest record from table using joins in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have recently started working on Laravel and now I'm having issue related joins.
Good human please look into this you might help me.

I have two table one is cable_users and other is cable_transactions connected with primary foreign key relation.
cable_users.id is in relation with cable_transactions.cableUser

all the transaction related to that cable user are get stored in cable_transactions table but now I want only the latest record from the cable_transactions  table.

```
$customers = DB::table('cable_users')            
        ->leftJoin('cable_transactions', 'cable_users.id', '=', 'cable_transactions.cableUser')
        ->where('cable_users.status', 'active')           
        ->select('cable_users.id', 'cable_users.name', 'cable_users.mobile', 'cable_users.address', 'cable_users.packageName', 'cable_users.status','cable_transactions.packageAmount','cable_transactions.advanceRemaining', 'cable_transactions.advanceAmount', 'cable_transactions.pendingAmount', 'cable_transactions.updated_at')
        ->orderBy('cable_users.id','DESC')   
        ->orderBy('cable_transactions.updated_at','ASC')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

from above code I'm getting all the data from cable_transactions table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Relations: ->latest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755804/laravel-eloquent-relations-latest)

Answer (score 0):

Try use take(1):

```
$customers = DB::table('cable_users')
->leftJoin('cable_transactions', 'cable_users.id', '=', 'cable_transactions.cableUser') ->where('cable_users.status', 'active')
->select('cable_users.id', 'cable_users.name', 'cable_users.mobile', 'cable_users.address', 'cable_users.packageName', 'cable_users.status','cable_transactions.packageAmount','cable_transactions.advanceRemaining', 'cable_transactions.advanceAmount', 'cable_transactions.pendingAmount', 'cable_transactions.updated_at') ->orderBy('cable_users.id','DESC')
->orderBy('cable_transactions.updated_at','ASC')
->take(1)
 ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: You can also use **first()** method instead of **get()** in order to return one object instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, that would be better)

Comment: Thank you @Underforest but that is returning only single data.