# last record data in database not the latest data

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I made table **conversations** and table **messages**, each conversation has many messages, and i want to show the latest message a conversation has, so i use this

```
$conversation->messages->last()->body
```

its return the last message in the record but not the latest,

this is my record

[database record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/515PU.png)

the latest messages not the last record , when i insert new message its not in the last record but inserted at some random order, that make the last() not work properly,

Comment: but i want to access it through eloquent collections, and not make a new query

Comment: i cant use the latest its said `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist.`

Comment: same error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755804/laravel-eloquent-relations-latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort a collection and get its last element.

Either sort in ascending order and take the last element:

```
$conversation->messages->sortBy('created_at')->last()->body
```

Or sort in descending order and take the first element:

```
$conversation->messages->sortByDesc('created_at')->first()->body
```

Whichever you consider more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Attach timestamp column in your table and then select messages order by timestamp desc.

You will get last message.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? i dont really understand

Comment: i want to access it through eloquent collection so that i dont need to make a new query